# Pause Media Player in case of phone call or user open a video or an audio in another program

Tags: java, android, media-player

I want to pause media player in case the user use another program to watch video
or the user receive a phone call like any multimedia app (YouTube ,...)

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override android methods which relate to the lifecycle of an android application

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mediaPlayer.stop(); //put your stop criteria here
    }

 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mediaPlayer.pause(); //put your pause criteria here
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); 
        mediaPlayer.play(); //put your resume criteria here
    }
```

you can simply override these methods to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer can be implemented as a service. Pause the service when the event happens using the BroadcastReceiver and you can again resume it using that. It would work in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AudioFocus (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus). In this way you will receive an Event when another App is taking "the ownership" of Audio Device to play its content/audio and then another Event will be raised when that App stops to play it and the "ownership" return to your App.